# How to apply changes in angularjs (ng-show)?

Tags: angularjs

I have form

```
<form ng-controller="SessionController" name="login_form">
  <div class="hide" ng-show='invalid_credentials'>Invalid email/pass</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click='login()'>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
utApp.controller('SessionController', ($scope, $cookieStore, ClientService) ->
  $scope.login = ->
    ...
    if something
      $scope.invalid_credentials = true
      return
```

on some conditions `$scope.invalid_credentials` is getting set to true, but div with error message is not being shown. How to show it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular doesn't re-check the value of your `invalid_credentials` variable. Using a function as your `ng-show` argument should work.

Comment: ok. i've changed ng-show to 'invalid_credentials()'
added function

$scope.invalid_credentials = ->
  console.log($scope.invalid_credentials_value)
  $scope.invalid_credentials_value

and changed condition to set invalid_credentials_value. As i see in console it shows true after clicking login. but div still hidden

Comment: Does your function return true, too?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will work... However, what you really needed to do is use $scope.$apply

```
utApp.controller "SessionController", ($scope, $cookieStore, ClientService) ->
  $scope.login = ->
    if something
      $scope.$apply (s) ->
        s.invalid_credentials = true
```

Generally, when you update the scope, and it doesn't update the UI... it's because you need to use [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply).

Comment: getting TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'

Comment: if i use $apply instead of apply i'm getting Error: $apply already in progress

Comment: Interesting. if apply is already in progress, then without the $apply, everything should be kosher, as $apply ensures that $digest is called. If the method $eval works, go ahead and use it I guess. But you shouldn't have to.